# Android - Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I made my project but I got this error:

```
 Error:Gradle: A problem occurred configuring root project 'RealEstate'.
 > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
 > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0.
   Required by:
     :RealEstate:unspecified
  > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0.
     > Could not get resource jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.5.0/gradle-1.5.0.pom'.
        > Could not GET jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.5.0/gradle-1.5.0.pom'.
           > Connection to http://www.somehost.org:8080 refuse
```

**My build.gradle file in root folder is:**

```
 buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
 }

 allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
   }
 }
```

**My gradle:wrapper.properties is:**

```
 #Wed Apr 10 15:27:10 PDT 2013
 distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
 distributionPath=wrapper/dists
 zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
 zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
 distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-all.zip
```

Also I put **gradle-1.5.0.pom** in this dirctory:
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository\com\android\tools\build\gradle\1.5.0

Can anyone help me?

Comment: what about `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta2'`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya after changing to 2.0.0-beta2 it gives me this error: Error:Connection timed out: connect. If you are behind an HTTP proxy, please configure the proxy settings either in IDE or Gradle.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31803610/gradle-behind-proxy-in-android-studio-1-3