# gradle project sync failed in android studio 1.5

Tags: android, gradle, synchronization

I migrate from `intellij 13` to `android studio 1.5`. I download and install it with its `jdk`. but as I import my `prole` , it shows this error :

[image]

I have search,But as you can see below I change `gradle version to 2.8` but It does not work.
I update `sdk manager/extras/android-support-residence`, It doesn't work too.

how can I solve it?

Comment: search by the error. Here is a referrence: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31803610/gradle-behind-proxy-in-android-studio-1-3

Comment: This might help... Although i dont know your problem.... https://www.google.co.in/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=connection+timed+out+connect.+if+you+are+behind+an+http+proxy&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=JV_6Vo6mI-iK8QfV74WwCA

Comment: where is the gradle.properties?

Comment: it is directly under project directory http://i.imgur.com/1bwJ24Z.png

Comment: do u mean gradle-wrapper.propertites? i use this in it: "#Wed Oct 21 11:34:03 PDT 2015
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-all.zip

systemProp.https.proxyHost=www.somehost.org
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyUser=userid
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=password
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost"

Comment: but the problem still again.