# Running Android Studio with an HTTP Proxy

Tags: gradle, proxy, android-studio-3.0

I just downloaded and installed the latest version of Android Studio (3.0.1) at work to start a new tablet project.  During setup it needed me to enter my proxy server information which I did.  I created an empty project and it asked me to accept or reject a couple of certificates one from Google Inc (*.google.com) and another from JetBrains s.r.o. (plugins.jetbrains.com).  I accepted them and they now show up in Settings -> Tools -> Server Certificates.  It has been able to download a number of packages, but after everything appears to be installed I get a message "Gradle project sync failed.  Basic functionality will not work properly."

There are a number of error messages that look like this:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.

Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
Required by:
    project :app
 > Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
    > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.pom'.
          > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.pom'.
                   > dl.google.com
```

I tried adding http and https proxy server information to the 'gradle.properties' as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31803610/gradle-behind-proxy-in-android-studio-1-3).

That changed the error message to this:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.

Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
Required by:
    project :app
 > Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
    > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.pom'.
          > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.pom'.
                   > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
                               > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
                                              > unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Further digging came up with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ).  Adding the URL to FireFox allows me to download the appcompat-v7-26.1.0.pom file but does not provide a "HTTPS certificate chain" to export a certificate from.  I am also not sure where I am supposed to get the keytool mentioned as well.

To verify that it is the proxy setup that is causing the problem I took my laptop home. Using my home network and turning off the HTTP Proxy caused a 3rd error (connection timed out) which was fixed by clearing the certificates.  So it appears that the certificates accepted in Android Studio are used by at least part of the process.   Now that I am back at work everything seems to work just fine.

There must be others out there running Android Studio with an HTTP Proxy set.  What is the "correct" way of fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the file

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\security>\cacerts
```

with the file from the jre (`%JAVA_HOME%\lib\security\cacerts`).

The certificates in the new cacerts file directed the android jre to go through the proxy server.